# Why can't I find cheap TQFP 44 sockets?

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I am trying to find a reasonably priced socket for a TQFP44 microcontroller but I am having a very hard time.

The only I found so far is this one:

http://uk.farnell.com/wells-cti/7010-044-6-08/socket-ic-zif-tqfp-44way/dp/1337653

I can get something similar for half the price if I buy it on Ebay from a Chinese seller, but it is still too expensive.

I think that I need the socket because the DIP version of the microcontroller is ten times bigger and there are no other surface mounted components on the board.  I am going to make only 4 boards, so I am investigating if I can avoid the extra cost of having the board assembled by the fab house.

Comment: Why do you need a socket? They are very expensive and aren't necessary in nearly all applications.

Comment: Use a proper direct link, please.

Comment: @Cristiano Is there any special reason why everything must be through hole? Even if other components are PTH, you could use SMD micro in general case.

Comment: @Cristiano - You probably won't find any cheap TQFP sockets, they are only really used for things like production programmers, testing, etc, as far as I know. I would get used to using/soldering SMDs (it's really not that hard), as you will limit you choice of components severely otherwise.

Comment: You don't have to go to a fab house to solder TQFP44 four (4) times. With little practice, TQFP44 can be soldered by hand.  You can practice on ready-made boards: on [TQFP to DIP adapters like these](http://www.beldynsys.com/quad.htm), for example.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is don't use a socket.  TQFP packages are intended for surface mounting, not socket use.  Clamshell type sockets do exist, but they are expensive due to being complex and because of low volume.  I doubt you'll find one that isn't at least several times the cost of the microcontroller you are trying to put in the circuit.

Why do you think you need a socket?  There should be no need to replace a microcontroller on a board once mounted, and nowadays with in circuit debugging that is not a reason for a socket either.